# The structure we used Help/ Help to

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

ThTake this statement " Good friends help build your confident "

what we are said about help build ? its idioms

can i use help to build

Comment: Confident is an adjective; the noun you want is confidence.

Answer (score 1):

After 'help' you can use the bare infinitive - 'help do something' or the to-infinitive - 'help **to** do something'. Both mean the same, but using 'to' is slightly more formal.

[Bare infinitive (BBC English)](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv226.shtml#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20difference%20in%20meaning.&text=Help%20is%20a%20verb%20that,it%20sometimes%20sounds%20more%20informal.)

Answer (score 0):

> Good friends help build your confidence.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help_INF%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%2Chelp_INF%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t3%3B%2Chelp_INF%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhelp%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelped%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelps%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelping%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Chelp_INF%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhelp%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelped%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelps%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelping%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0#t3%3B%2Chelp_INF%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhelp%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bhelped%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelps%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelping%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Chelp_INF%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhelp%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bhelped%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelps%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhelping%20to%20build%20_PRON_%20confidence%3B%2Cc0) shows that the pattern `"help build <pronoun> confidence"` is more common than `"help to build <pronoun> confidence"`.

[image]

There is a phrasal verb with *build*, [to *build up something*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/build-up-sth?q=build%20up%20%28sth%29), which can be used with things like strength, experience, success, wealth.

> Good friends help build up your confidence.

> Good friends help build your confidence up.